# Rmarkdown no longer working after 1.0.136 R Studio update

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I recently updated my R Studio to version 1.0.136 and now have the following error when trying to knit documents:

[image]

I've run `getOptions("repos")` and would seem to be set to the appropriate CRAN mirror:

```
                       CRAN 
"https://cran.rstudio.com/" 
attr(,"RStudio")
[1] TRUE
```

Running `devtools::install_github("rstudio/rmarkdown")` also does not solve the problem and the same error results.

Any thoughts or more information I can provide?

Comment: Note: I get the following error when trying to install through devtools: ERROR: dependency ‘rprojroot’ is not available for package ‘rmarkdown’

Comment: Shot in the dark, but does `install.packages("knitr",dependencies = TRUE)` help?

Comment: What version of R do you have installed? You might need to upgrade it if these packages are not installable in your current version.

Comment: R appears up to date and re-installing knitr does not solve the issue.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Curious if you ever found a resolution.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when I upgraded to 1.0.136. Specifically, `rprojroot1.0 is not available`.

In my case, installing the latest version of R (3.3.3) fixed the problem. (You have to point RStudio at the new version, in the "Tools...Global Options..." menu.)

I had been using version 3.1.2 and presumably the latest packages required for knitr needed newer. This discussion suggests as much: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000740667-Rmarkdown-not-working-with-RStudio-Version-1-0-136

Comment: Yep - this worked for me too.  Upgraded to 3.4.1 from CRAN, then restarted RStudio.

Comment: Actually - 3.4.1 did not work for all my packages so I went down to 3.3.3.  That seems to be the best course.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error by downloading the latest version. The new version asks you to download the dependent packages automatically.